# Use notifyDataSetChanged(); after updating SQLite from other activity and inside the same activity

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

**Summary**: I am creating a sample memo app with SQLite as its database.

**MainActivity**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);    

    lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.memo_list_view);

    Cursor c = SplashActivity.db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM memos", null);
    if(c.getCount()!=0) {
        while(c.moveToNext()) {

            memoDetails = new MemoDetails();

            memoDetails.setmMemoId(c.getString(0));
            memoDetails.setmMemoTitle(c.getString(1));
            memoDetails.setmCreatedDate(c.getString(3));
            memoDetails.setmAlarmedDate(c.getString(4));
            memos.add(memoDetails);

        }
        c.close();
        customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(this, memos);
        lv.setAdapter(customAdapter);
    }

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    customAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Then this is the activity where I add my memo

**AddMemoActivity** (this is the listener I use)

```
 saveMemo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v1) {
            if(memoTitle.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0 ||
                memoContent.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0) {
                showMessage("Error", "Please Enter All Values");    
            } else {

                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss");
                String currentDateandTime = sdf.format(new Date());

                SplashActivity.db.execSQL("INSERT INTO memos VALUES(null,'" 
                        + memoTitle.getText() + "','" 
                        + memoContent.getText() + "','" 
                        + currentDateandTime + "','"
                        + currentDateandTime + "','0');");

            showMessage("Success", "Memo is Saved.");   
            }
        }
    });
```

On this "Adding Memo" part, my problem is when I leave my **AddMemoActivity** and return to my **MainActivty**, it doesn't update my listview.

Second is my delete part,

**MainActivity**

```
 findViewById(R.id.del_memo).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v1) {              
            DialogInterface.OnClickListener dialogClickListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    switch (which){
                    case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                        String deleteIds = null;
                        for (MemoDetails p : customAdapter.getBox()) {
                            if (p.mCheckBox){
                                if(deleteIds == null) {
                                    deleteIds = p.getmMemoId();
                                } else {
                                    deleteIds += ", " + p.getmMemoId();
                                }

                            }
                        }

                        SplashActivity.db.execSQL("DELETE FROM memos WHERE id IN ('"+deleteIds+"')");
                        customAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), deleteIds,
                                   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        break;

                    case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
                        //No button clicked
                        break;
                    }
                }
            };

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MemoListActivity.this);
            builder.setMessage("Are you sure?").setPositiveButton("Yes", dialogClickListener)
                .setNegativeButton("No", dialogClickListener).show();  
        }
    });
```

As you can see, I already added **customAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();** after deletion but still no update.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Listview doesnt update by updating DB. You need to update the list you gave the adapter and then call notifyDataChange().

So update the list you gave the listview's udapter everytime you change the DB data.

Just update the `memos` list then call notify data change.

Answer (score 0):

`notifyDataSetChanged` alone won't help, you need to update the list you passed the adapter too. I use SugarORM for my SQL operations so it looks like this for me:

Initial filling the adapter with data:

```
for (User user : SugarRecord.listAll(User.class)) {
    userNames.add(user.getName());
}
swipeActionAdapter = new SwipeActionAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, userNames));
```

Then after adding or deleting a user:

```
userNames.clear();
for (User user : SugarRecord.listAll(User.class)) {
        userNames.add(user.getName());
}
swipeActionAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```